# JS always returns an empty model

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public string SomeString { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.TestModel

<script>
    function Test()
    {
        var modelDataJSON = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';
        alert(modelDataJSON);
    }
</script>

@{Model.SomeString = "asdf";}

<button type="button" onclick="Test()">Test</button>
```

JS alert always return JSON where all fields are set to null:
    {"SomeString:null}

Comment: try adding the `@{Model.SomeString = "asdf";}` line before the script block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's normal behaviour...you should change the value before the script block like below...

```
@{Model.SomeString = "asdf";}

<script>
    function Test()
    {
        var modelDataJSON = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';
        alert(modelDataJSON);
    }
</script>
```

What happens is that before the page is rendered, Razor will resolve all the "symbols and expressions" specified in the view, so, this line...

```
var modelDataJSON = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';
```

will be replaced with the actual value of the model before the page gets sent to the browser...

```
var modelDataJSON = '{"SomeString":null}';
```

However, if you change the value before the the script block Razor will replace the expression with the current value. You can easily see this by viewing the page source on your browser how the value gets replaced with a "hard-coded" string

Comment: Thank you, that clarifies the situation, although there are some problems. I was hoping with this code to get the current values ​​of properties model - **at the time the excecution** method Test. Is there any such possibility?

Comment: absolutely, you only have to keep in mind that there are no models on the client browser...just html elements. That means...do not attempt to manipulate a MODEL with javascript, instead you should be manipulating page elements such as textboxes, hidden fields, etc. Keep the model values in page elements and manipulate the elements

Comment: Thank you. I will work with the elements, just no other choice.